# Embedding File Content and Media files in a HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to embed different types of files and media into a HTML page. The file types may include video , audio, image, pdf , doc etc. I have gone through the HTML 5 standards where we have the video and audio tags to embed these media files. However i was wondering if there is a single tag or a 3rd party plugin which can be used to display / embed all these types of files? Basically my requirement is that my HTML page should be able to display all the above types of content.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks ! <embed> would work. Do you happen to know any other plugins? also i would like to create playlists containing multiple files playing in a sequence

Comment: Ya know, to have true multi-file capabilities, you will have to make the user download it. If they have a plug-in, they could use <embed>, but I have never seen a plugin for .doc, for example.